# Beam TextIO write NullPointerException because destination is null

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am using the Apache Beam DirectRunner, and I have defined a pipeline as follows:

```
val p = Pipeline.create(options)
p.apply(Create.of("/tmp/dc/foo.txt"))
        .apply(FileLoader())
        .apply(SaveLineToRedis())
        .apply(AddToRedisIndex())
        .apply(MatchTransform())
        .apply(GroupByKey.create())
        .apply(TextIO.writeCustomType<KV<String, Iterable<SimpleMatcherResult>>>().to("/tmp/bar"))
```

The writing out fails with:

```
13:45:47.247 [direct-runner-worker] INFO  org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles - Opening writer 83c36e3f-7e1f-406c-a9c6-f3ab4bac1cb7 for window org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@29caf222 pane PaneInfo{isFirst=true, isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=0, onTimeIndex=0} destination null
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:342)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:312)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:206)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:62)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
        at de.techmatrix.dc.matcher.MainKt.main(Main.kt:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.DynamicFileDestinations$ConstantFilenamePolicy.formatRecord(DynamicFileDestinations.java:49)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn.processElement(WriteFiles.java:718)
```

The destination is returned by the `DynamicFileDestinations` as `null`:

```
public Void getDestination(UserT element) {
  return (Void) null;
}
```

**Update:** This works with `FileIO`:

```
        .apply(FileIO.writeDynamic<String, KV<String, Iterable<SimpleMatcherResult>>>()
                .by { it.value.first().matchedKey }.withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .via(Contextful.fn({ mapper.writeValueAsString(it) }), TextIO.sink())
                .to("/tmp/bar")
                .withNaming{ _ -> defaultNaming("matches", "txt")})
```

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you didn't specify `withFormatFunction()` (and Beam failed to validate this and give a better error message). The NPE is from [this line](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/71e2526ee092fd535960dd76afa6420ce01a9e90/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/DynamicFileDestinations.java#L49) invoking the (missing) format function.

In the second snippet, it is specified - `Contextful.fn({ mapper.writeValueAsString(it) })` - so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using `TextIO.writeCustomType()` implicitly uses `DynamicDestinations`. Calling `TextIO.writeCustomType().to("/tmp/bar")` is just setting the file name prefix for the file to be written. See the [TextIO.TypedWrite.to()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.TypedWrite.html#to-java.lang.String-) definition. Do you actually need to write to a dynamic destination?

You can write to a text file simply using the `TextIO.Write` transform. See the [TextIO](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html) definition for reference and examples. You'll need an additional transform step to transform `KV<String, Iterable<SimpleMatcherResult>>` to a `String` type.

Comment: What does it mean "using DynamicDestination"? What are the implications of that apart from NPEing? When I tried on the pipeline `.apply(TextIO.write().to("/tmp/bar"))` it fails with compile error because this is not a `PTransform`.

Comment: Writing to dynamic destinations allows you to determine the output file of an element at runtime. The output file is usually based on some value of the element itself (i.e. timestamp of element). `DynamicDestinations` is the class in Apache Beam which enables this functionality. Reference: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSink.DynamicDestinations.html.